# How to show rows when column match criteria?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

How can I define a measure to set a condition to show values of apples when column = fruits contains the string `apple`?

I've tried this but I only see query batch complete with errors.

```
MEASURE Table1[apples] = IF(SEARCH("apple",'Table1'[Fruits]),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to return a sum of the column `'Table1'[Value]` for those rows where the `'Table1'[Fruits]`-column contains the string "apple", you should use:

```
MEASURE Table1[apples] = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'Table1'[Value] ),
    KEEPFILTERS(
        SEARCH ( "apple", 'Table1'[Fruits], 1, 0 ) <> 0
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I'm working on Dax Studio, Excel 2016 and it seems the function `CONTAINSSTRING()` is not available. I get error `CONTAINSSTRING It is not a valid table, variable or function name`

Comment: Ok - modified my answer to use the equivalent `SEARCH` expression ([`CONTAINSSTRING`](https://dax.guide/containsstring/) is really just an easier way to do the same thing, but unfortunately its not supported in Excel).

Comment: Thanks so much for he help, but I don't know why even I have numbers in column "Value", I receive error saying that SUM cannot work with values of type string

Comment: Change the data type of the column to “Whole Number”, “Decimal Number” or “Currency”, depending on what you need.